# Issue when animating on hover effects with callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am having this issue when I am using the hover event in jQuery. I have two containers side by side. I have hover events on both of them. When hover, a div with additional info slides up into frame. When you hover off, it slides back down.

Simple right? When you hover on an element it should remove the "hide-me" class and start sliding the info up (animating). When you hover off of an element the "hide-me" class should be removed once the animation is complete.This works fine when you hover on and hover off onto an element that is not a grid-item. When you hover off of an item onto another grid-item it seems to just add the class "hide-me" to the currently hovered element. Even though the hover off event hasn't fired yet.

Anyways enough talk here is the code on JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/joemoe_1984/2k22yLmd/2/

For testing here is what works:

Hover from below/above image then hover out from below/above image

For testing how it doesn't work:

Hover from below/above image then hover out onto other image

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify a bit as I had an answer that got me the effect I wanted but didn't exactly solve the issue I was having exactly. I would like to know why the animation callbacks on complete don't properly work when hovering from one image to the other. This is the part that has been bugging me the most. When you hover on an image and then out it removes the class on hover then adds the class after the animation called from the hover out event finishes. This is the expected behaviour. When I hover over an image then onto the other image you will see that instead of adding the class to the first image on hover out, it adds it to the image you are current hovering. Its as if the animation callback is calling the wrong callback function once it animates up on hover.

The on hover state should never have the class added. It should be removed at this point. The class should also not be added during any of the animation states.

Just in case links aren't ok, here is the full html, css and javascript:

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-container">

        <div class="grid-item">
            <a href="#" class="grid-inner">
                <div class="grid-image">
                    <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/metroid/images/8/86/Samus_artwork_11.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100516174330" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="grid-info hide-me">
                    <div class="middle-align">
                        <h4 class="grid-title">Some title</h4>
                        <div class="grid-details">
                            This is some info about this item
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
            <a href="#" class="grid-inner">
                <div class="grid-image">
                    <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/metroid/images/8/86/Samus_artwork_11.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100516174330" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="grid-info hide-me">
                    <div class="middle-align">
                        <h4 class="grid-title">Some title</h4>
                        <div class="grid-details">
                            This is some info about this item
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-item {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.grid-inner {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.grid-info {
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.hide-me {
    display: none;
}
.middle-align {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.grid-item').hover(hover_in, hover_out);

    function hover_in(e) {
        $info = $(e.currentTarget).find('.grid-info');
        target_height = $(e.currentTarget).height();
        $info.css('top', target_height).removeClass('hide-me');

        $info.stop().animate({
            'top': 0,
        }, 500, function() {
            console.log('animated up');
        });
    }

    function hover_out(e) {
        $info = $(e.currentTarget).find('.grid-info');
        target_height = $(e.currentTarget).height();

        $info.stop().animate({
            'top': target_height,
        }, 500, function() {
            console.log('animated down');
            $info.addClass('hide-me');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use a different class name of them and distinguish each class in script?

Comment: @AlfredWoo That won't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I figured it out. It turned out to be a scope issue. The problem stemmed from using e.currentTarget (or this) within the hover event scope. I stored that instance into a variable and then later used it in the callback of the animation sequence.

It appears that the current target changes from when the animation callback uses it giving me the unexpected results. For the animation callbacks I should have used the instance (this) within the scope of the animation callback function like so:

```
$info.stop().animate({
    'top': target_height,
}, 500, function() {
    console.log('animated down');
    $(this).addClass('hide-me'); // this refers to the current animated object. This is the correct one.
    $info.addClass('wrong-one'); // $info refers to the current hover event target which is the on hover item when it should be the hover off item. This is incorrect
});
```

You can test it out and see that going from one image to the next will now add the class `hide-me` to the correct one and add the class `wrong-one` to the currently hovered item which is not the expected behaviour I was looking for.

Thanks to everyone for pitching in on the answers and providing alternative solutions but this was real issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting using `.show()` after call to `.stop()` for `.removeClass('hide-me')` at `hover_in`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.grid-item').hover(hover_in, hover_out);

  function hover_in(e) {
    $info = $(e.currentTarget).find('.grid-info');
    target_height = $(e.currentTarget).height();
    $info.css('top', target_height) //.removeClass('hide-me')    
      .stop()
      .show()
      .animate({
        'top': 0,
      }, 500, function() {
        console.log('animated up');
      });
  }

  function hover_out(e) {
    $info = $(e.currentTarget).find('.grid-info');
    target_height = $(e.currentTarget).height();

    $info.stop().animate({
      'top': target_height,
    }, 500, function() {
      console.log('animated down');
      $info.addClass('hide-me');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.grid-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.grid-info {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
.middle-align {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>

  <h1>Animation grid</h1>

  <div class="grid-container">

    <div class="grid-item">
      <a href="#" class="grid-inner">
        <div class="grid-image">
          <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/metroid/images/8/86/Samus_artwork_11.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100516174330" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-info hide-me">
          <div class="middle-align">
            <h4 class="grid-title">Some title</h4>
            <div class="grid-details">
              This is some info about this item
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <a href="#" class="grid-inner">
        <div class="grid-image">
          <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/metroid/images/8/86/Samus_artwork_11.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100516174330" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-info hide-me">
          <div class="middle-align">
            <h4 class="grid-title">Some title</h4>
            <div class="grid-details">
              This is some info about this item
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2k22yLmd/3/

Comment: It does work and I had something similar before but I guess what I wanted to know more about is why does my implementation not work? It seems that the callbacks for the animation class don't seem to work properly. I will give you an upvote anyways but if you can answer that then I will give you the correct answer for sure. I will update my question.

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 Toggling `display:none` is not necessary to achieve expected effect https://jsfiddle.net/2k22yLmd/4/

Comment: _"but didn't exactly solve the issue I was having exactly. I would like to know why the animation callbacks on complete don't properly work when hovering from one image to the other."_ What is expected result of `.animate()` callback functions ?

Comment: My problem goes a little further than animating the effect. I would like to add a class to the item when animation completes. If you take a look in the inspector from either Chrome or Firefox (or whichever you use), you can see that when I hover from one image to the second, the second image gets the class "hide-me" added when it should only be removed at this point. This is the real issue. Sorry if I explained this part poorly.

Comment: This works fine when playing around with the hover with only one image. But when you hover off of the one image right to the next one, it doesn't seem to add the classes properly.

Comment: Is requirement for only hovered image to have `className` added ? For only one image to have the `className` at one time ? _"I would like to add a class to the item when animation completes"_ What is the purpose of adding `className` to an element when animation completes ?

Comment: I would say, have it work with the "hide-me" class for starters. When you hover on, it should remove class before animating. When hover off, it should add class after animating.

Comment: Keep in mind in its current state it does work when dealing with the one image hovering on and off. But not when hovering on an image then hovering off to go to the next. This is the part that I am having troubles with.

Comment: When the element is hovered it should not have class `hide-me` , until animation completes ? When animation completes, add `className` `"hide-me"` to the element ? What is expected result if another image is hovered ?

Comment: no it should not have `hide-me` when hovering initially. If the class exists until animation completes sliding up then it won't show at all. So on hover adds the class and then off hover removes it when done animating. The expected result for another image to be hovered on should be the same but thats where things get wonky.

Comment: _"then off hover removes it when done animating"_ Those are two different events. Is requirement to have `"hide-me"` added as a `className` only while the element is being animated ?

Comment: Sorry, on hover and off hover both call an animation event on the element. What I meant was off hover calls the animation to slide down then once complete it adds the class `hide-me` again.

Comment: The `"hide-me"` `class` should only be added when the element is not being animated ? Attempting to determine logic of process ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103809/discussion-between-guest271314-and-joemoe1984).

Comment: not exactly lol. `hide-me` should exist on first load. It should be removed when `grid-item` is hovered (not after animation). It should be removed after sliding back down which is called from hovering off (so hover off calls animation, then when animation is done remove `hide-me` class).
I think StackOverflow wants us to move this to a chat discussion.